# gitlab-cicd cant build jar

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci

There is a problem when running my gitlab-ci. Building java via mvn and packing the built Jar file into docker.
When running ci with both package and dockerise stages, then a jar file not building. According to the logs, it is there, but if i look along the path where it supposedly gathered, the file is missing. But if i remove the dockerise stage, then everything works fine and the jar file is built and i see it on the server. It seems that the dockerise stage somehow overwrites the upper assembly stages. Also, if all commands, mvn package, docker build, docker push, are left in the one stage, within the script, everything builds as it should. I can't figure out what the problem is. Who can help and tell what's wrong? Here is my CI code

```
image: maven:latest

variables:
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository"
  APP_NAME: app-api
  
cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/repository

stages:
  - package
  - dockerise

Package artifacts:
  stage: package
  image: openjdk:17-alpine
  tags: [dev]
  only:
    - release
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_OPTS clean package
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/*.jar

Dockerise:
  stage: dockerise
  image: docker:latest
  tags: [dev]
  only:
    - release
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - cd app
    - docker build -t $CI_OPENSHIFT_REGISTRY/dev/$APP_NAME:latest .
    - docker login "$CI_OPENSHIFT_REGISTRY" -p $(oc whoami -t) -u "$OPENSHIFT_USER"
    - docker push  $CI_OPENSHIFT_REGISTRY/dev/$APP_NAME:latest
```

Comment: share the logs or dockerfile if you are missing files then it could be path issue in gitlb

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to remove "cd app" command?
I think that default working directory is "/" in docker image, so the artifact would be copied to there by gitlab.

Comment: no, its ok with "cd app" The main problem is, there is no jar file, while running all stages. When i comment stage Dockerise, my gilab-ci build jar file, i see it on my runner machine, and can run manualy in terminal, docker build, and get image with this build file. But when i turn on stage Dockerise, again, stage package "successful" but without jar

Comment: @user3904465 got it. So did you really see the jar file? Because GitLab Runner should only pack your jar file as artifacts.zip and upload it to your gitlab server. you shouldn't see pure jar file. How about you image in registry? did it update? 
you can go to pipeline page to see whether your artifact could be download.

Comment: maybe i'm doing something wrong, but, yes, when running ci with only stage package, a see a target dir, inside a lot of files, and jar file called app-api.jar which i need to pack into docker container